# html paste handler wont trigger on a element

Tags: javascript, html

In below html code snippet, `paste-element` is not enabled for paste when called `.focus` on it, can any html expert help me why it wont work this way.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Display Text Input Fields</h1>
    <div id="paste-element" tabindex="0" onpaste="alert(1)" > --> Clicking or tab into this will enable element for paste
        paste here
    </div>
    <p onclick="document.getElementById('paste-element').focus()">Click here, wont enable paste</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Same question is being discussed in react forum - https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/9769

Comment: `onclick="document.getElementById("paste-element").focus()"` ... fortunately, `'` and `"` are interchangable in javascript ... so use one inside the other, otherwise your onclick makes no sense - hint: currently, your onclick is assigned the value `"document.getElementById("` - you'll probably see a bunch of errors if you open the *browser **developer** tools console*

Comment: So sorry, that was my bad while framing markup for this question, edited the question with proper markup.

Comment: I'd suggest you to update your code to the new century and stop using inline javascript. inline js is hardly readable, difficult to maintain and so '90s!

Comment: Stop using unsafe inline `on*` handlers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: @LelioFaieta - Yes, it is represented here for simple demonstration. We are using typescript/angular in my real project. Sorry if its too trivial.

Comment: @RoToRa - elements with tabindex set will trigger `paste` event